# SecurityException occurred

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine, flicker, securityexception

I have read, that it could be possible to fuse `UnityEngine` with `Winforms`, so that is what I am trying to do. I am trying to use a sine wave to control the flickering between colors on a button in `Winform`. However I am getting a `SecurityException` which I do not konw how to solve.

```
    private void DisplayMessage(string messge)
    {
        int numVal;
        //SPELL.Text += messge + Environment.NewLine;

        numVal = Convert.ToInt32(messge);
        udpSock1.Close();
        if (numVal == 83)
        {

        //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
        //Application.Run(form1);
            BCI1 form1 = new BCI1();
            //Application.Run(form1);
            form1.ShowDialog();
            //stopwatch.Start();
            SPELL.Text = SPELL.Text + form1.LET;

            udpSock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSock1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
            buffer = new byte[1024];

            newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpSock1.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, udpSock1);

            //udpSock.Disconnect(true);
            //udpSock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8050));
        }
```

Here I open the new form, and the form hen diplays som characters, which can chosen, hereafter the form closes agian, and you return to the main, form 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Flicker
{
    static class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct Message
        {
            public IntPtr hWnd;
            public int msg;
            public IntPtr wParam;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public uint time;
            public Point p;
        }

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool PeekMessage(out Message msg, IntPtr hWnd, uint messageFilterMin, uint messageFilterMax, uint flags);

        static Form1 form;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            form = new Form1();
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
            Application.Run(form);
        }

        static void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Message message;
            while (!PeekMessage(out message, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                form.UpdateFrame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the form:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Flicker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            stopwatch.Start();
        }

        public void UpdateFrame()
        {
            double cycleHz = 0.001;

            double wave = Math.Sin((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 2.0 * Math.PI) * cycleHz);

            if (wave > 0.0)
            {
                pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

just add pictureBox1 to your form in your designer.

i would suggest writing the whole application in Microsoft XNA - it is easier to learn than Unity3D :)

Comment: i dont see where you state The doublebuffering in your code?

Comment: Picturebox has doublebuffering enabled by default. You dont have to change anything.

Comment: how do i use the same function on more than one form in he program ?, I am openiung a new form when a picturebox is chosen, and closing it again. The flickering does not occur on the new form which is opend, but starts agian when it is closed and he main form is back. @JinJi

Comment: I would need the udateframe to run on more than 1 form, how can I do that, the other forms opens and closes when a target with in the form is chosen.

Comment: Is it possible to do with more than 1 form@JinJi?

Comment: I have edited he code above, so you can see how I am opening he new form.

Comment: you should ask a new Stackoverflow question, so other people may also help you :) (and so i can get more points, if you upvote my answer, haha - that's a joke ;)

Comment: I have tested the code, and it is precise, however I need i o work on multiple forms.

Comment: I have now asked a new question, it is the last hing I need for the progam to run as it should. Hopefully it can be done.

Comment: XNA is now dead, is not it? And Unity3d is actively developed.